# Push value to observableArray collection

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm getting following error when I want to `push` items after I set `null` to `observableArray()`

> can not read property push of null

```
self.roomMembers(null);

// I got error here
self.roomMembers.push(new member(user));
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what's the point for having observableArray with null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear your observable array and then push to it do not use `self.roomMembers(null)` instead use `self.roomMembers([])`

Answer (score 1):

To clear the observable array you can do `self.roomMembers([])`, as @jj689 stated, or you can use the ko removeAll method: `self.roomMembers.removeAll()` . removeAll will also return current values as an array.